# "Bear with me" for how long?

Tags: phrase-usage

I know you say to someone ***Bear with me*** if it is for a few minutes:

> ***bear with me​/​us*** - used as a polite way of asking someone *to be patient while you do or finish something*
>
> - If you just *bear with me **for a few more minutes***, we’ll have all the paperwork finished. ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bear-with))

Can you say

> Bear with me ***for half an hour***?

or is that definitely too long?

Edit: Thanks to the comment below, I would like to clarify the situation I am refering to. When you go for an appointment let's say, and the person receiving you is not quite available yet, they tell you "bear with me, please". This is the use I am interested in. I always thought you can only use this expression with a few minutes, but today someone addressed me saying:

> Please bear with me half an hour, and then we can speak.

(That person, like me, is not a native speaker, which is why maybe they forgot to say "***for*** half an hour"). I was wondering if you can say that.

Comment: My mother bore with my father for 60 years. [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bear_with) just says 'be patient or tolerant with someone'. Cambridge, Collins,  the same. Macmillan seems to be in a minority. Merriam Webster's thesaurus just gives 'suffer, stand'.

Comment: Would you really want someone sitting there staring at you for half an hour while you tried to finish something? Someone can bear with someone for a long time, but as a phrase where you’re asking for someone’s patience there are better choices in my opinion.

Comment: @ColleenV Exactly that is what I thought. But I wanted to know if there are "time" limitations to the expression specified anywhere or in the conscience of natives...

Comment: I don’t think it’s an egregious misuse, but I would prefer something like “Just give me a half an hour, then we can speak.” For me, “Bear with me” has a connotation of “stay right here, I’m almost done” in the context you’re talking about.

Comment: @ColleenV Thank you for confirming my intuition.

Comment: Yes, that totally works. The duration is independent of the idiom. I could tell my drug dealer, "Bear with me; I'll have the cash in two days," and that would sound natural.

Comment: Oops, now I am confused...

Comment: I think it can be said without “raising too many eyebrows”, but I would prefer something else. It’s not wrong or completely inappropriate. I don’t disagree with @JeffreyCarney. I didn’t write an answer because this is just my opinion.

Comment: @ColleenV, I think we are describing different personal experiences of this idiom. Mine is simply more expansive.

Comment: If you want to piss someone off, sure you can! :)

Comment: Well, I must say I didn't expect such a variety of reaction. It may vary according to each person's experience, I gather. Instinctively, though, for "half an hour", I would have also said something like, "Could you wait for half an hour? Then we can speak."

Comment: I Googled, and most of the hits come back with "a moment," "a few minutes," etc. I'm inclined to think it would depend on the context. If the normal response would be instantaneous, you would say, "bear with me a minute." If it were a day, you might say, "bear with me a few days." (Perhaps my life experiences have been intense at times.) But I cannot imagine a situation where you would say, "Bear with me for a year." So I was wrong when I said, "The duration is independent of the idiom."

Comment: I emailed someone today and asked them to bear with me until next Monday, when our database guy comes back from leave.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Good example. However, I am speaking about a face to face situation when your appointment is **now**, and they ask you to bear with them.

Comment: I think any realistic time frame. If I am in agony, I will bear with the dentist for maybe 2 minutes. If it is an appointment for a haircut, I might be OK with half an hour, if the stock of magazines is good enough.

Comment: I don’t think people use longer time frames here naturally. It’s either for a short while or for an unspecified longer period.

Answer (score 4):

"Bear with me" does tend to have a split timeframe.  It usually holds meanings of "just a moment" or "forever."  But less often in the middle.

Common:
"Bear with me for a few minutes."

"I know our marriage is hard because of my job, but please bear with me, I'm doing my best."

Less common:
"Bear with me for a few hours."

Still, any time frame is not that unusual because the phrase is mostly asking for sympathy towards the person for the delay or inconvenience.